# How to change template file in Joomla 3.x

Tags: templates, joomla, components

I am making my own component for Joomla.

Is it possible to change the template file (admin login specifically) in my component, or even additional plugin? I just want to add a button or href in admin login form.

- normal admin login form
- install my extension
- changed admin login form

Any help appreciated. Of course I can edit the template file manually, but I want to make it automatically while installing extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a system plugin which performs the modification on this page. It's not quite straight forward, but it should work. The AfterRender-Event sounds useful.

https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/System#onAfterRender

Comment: Well, i have found a solution. AfterRender is event which occur after page is rendered. Instead of AfterRender i used OnBeforeRender to add javascript code which add a button on my login form. Thanks for the reply, your answer is helpful for me.

Comment: You can use the AfterRender-Event to change the generated HTML-Code which would make additional JavaScript unnecessary.